# Fate of light ray

Tags: optics

[image]

This question has been on my mind since I first learned optics. Where will the light ray go?

First, I thought of it taking a U turn. But, I don't think that will happen. Now I have studied a bit about wave optics and I think that the light will go... everywhere? Can someone please explain it in realm of ray optics? I wouldn't  mind a bit about wave optics. Just don't go deep down there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This totally depends on the shape of the mirror surface at the exact point which the light is incident on. It's also very difficult to say exactly what will happen because we can't - in practice - obtain a single ray of light hitting the exact edge as we do in theory.

We are normally never bothered about edge phenomena when we talk about optics, so we never really describe *what* the edge is like.

If you keep zooming in, you're bound to see that even the edge is indeed flat, at least for a tiny thing like a photon. In that case, the light will be incident normally and will reflect with a deviation of $180^\circ$.

If you choose to think that it isn't flat ever, and up to the last molecule forms a corner, in that case I guess the light would diffract about that point, going in all directions.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture is misrepresenting the physics.

Your `light ray` is drawn as a line with a relative small width. It will therefore normally be considered as a symbolic representation of a mathematical line(with *no* width).

Your `mirror` is likewise seen as a perfect mathematical surface with a perfect angle.

These **perfect mathematical entities does not exist in our physical world** - they are only models used to visualize the physics. If you draw a better picture(without mathematical ambiguity) either with a fat ray, or a rounded angel, your question disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Because the derivative of the mirror angle is discontinuous, the mirror does not have a specific angle at x = 0, so the reflection angle is undefined at x = 0.

On the other hand, you might consider the effect of shining a bundle of light rays with a finite diameter (centered on x=0) on the origin. Obviously, half of the light will go to the left and half to the right. As you narrow the beam, the proportion reflected in each direction stays the same, so the limit case (when the beam diameter goes to zero) is equal reflection in each direction.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of whatever physics is assumed, if the cone has perfect symmetry, then, by symmetry, the ray is directly reflected back along the direction it came from.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that it's a quantum mechanical question.  The location of the point where the mirrors meet can be represented by a mathematical expression and various values in that expression can be chosen to make it as small as we like.  Similarly, the light wave is expressed with other values which can make it wider than the mirror's point.  Then we have a probabilities that it will go right or left.  Until we observe the result, we have to give it both paths but still know how much it's in one or the other.  (I think)