# What happens to light at sharp points?

Tags: optics, visible-light, waves, spectroscopy

[image]

At the tip of the sharp point shown, what will happen to light incident on it. 
This curiosity was invoked by a friend and also my childhood of watching shiny pointed swords in cartoons.
Original Question asked to me:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17375026#17375026

Comment: Can you give more details? What kind of light? Coherent? Are you interested in the shadow? At what angle is the light incident?

Comment: @BMS: "Hypothetically speaking, what'd happen if some perfect ray of light issued from a perfect point source is projected upon a point of the reflector at which there exists infinitely many tangents (like a kink)?"

Comment: Can you add this to your question? Not everyone reads these comments.

Comment: I don't think there is a trivial answer to that. It may depend on the shape of the cusp and the angle, under which it is illuminated. In general, many shapes will show a reflection at such points, but I don't think that's a universally valid conclusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fate of light ray](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110120/fate-of-light-ray)

Comment: @JohnRennie: Mark it as duplicate, then. I agree it's the same question. (My defense, I did search for an answer and ask around a bit)

Comment: @Nick: searchng for duplicates is very hit and miss. I only found the duplicate because I remembered it as being an interesting question and knew what to search for.

Answer (score 4):

A "sharp" tip typically has a finite curvature; there will be a very small part of the "tip" that is therefore angled at such a way that light will be reflected off it. The sharper the tip, the smaller the radius of curvature, and the smaller the "twinkle" or glint.

The second effect is diffraction: Light that passes an object will be diffracted. For example, light passing the eye of a needle shows a characteristic Fresnel diffraction pattern (image from http://www.sciencephoto.com/):

[image]

I could not easily locate an image of the sharp end of the needle, but I think you get the idea of what it would look like...